# Show/Hide a button without using setState in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to merge two buttons into one such that when we press the current button the other button will show up while hiding the button clicked and vice versa.
I can do it using states but that will force a re-rendering, I have read the Direct Manipulation documentation but not able to understand how to pass the nativeProps.

Comment: You need to make use of refs along with setNativeProps. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html. That should be straight forward. Also for styling `display: 'none'` might help.

Comment: Please provide a code example.